# Checkstyle 8.41.1 throws exception when configuring a custom Google checkstyle.xml in IntelliJ 2021

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I have upgraded to the latest Checkstyle plugin (8.41.1) using IntelliJ 2021.
I'm trying to configure a custom google checkstyle xml file, so I took the lates example from [Github](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) and tried to set it as config file to the checkstyle plug but I'm getting the following exception

```
com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - cannot initialize module JavadocMethod - Property 'accessModifiers' does not exist, please check the documentation
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:473)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:201)
    at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.service.cmd.OpCreateChecker.execute(OpCreateChecker.java:61)
...
...
```

If I'm setting the builtin Google check then it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

> I took the lates example from Github

This is the issue. You should be using the config that was built for the version of checkstyle you are using. You pulled in master's config which contains new features that have not been released.

See https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/49d1ea3835e017133ada46555d2214e017fc6fe2/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Comment: I see! ok, so my next question would be where can I find `google_check.xml` that is compatible with 8.41.1 ? I just would like to configure a bit the default one that comes with IntelliJ.

Comment: The link provided is for 8.41.1 . You can also use the one that comes embedded with Checkstyle. I don't know how IntelliJ accesses it, but usually it is by specifying `/google_checks.xml` as the file name.

Comment: I'm a little confused, wasn't `accessModifiers` released in 7.5? Shouldn't a config that uses it work with 8.41.1? 

https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/releasenotes.html

Comment: @AustinBrown be careful on what you check you are looking at. This issue is for JavadocMethod which had access modifiers added in 8.42 . You can check all check documentation at https://checkstyle.org/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod_Properties , which lists the version it was first available.

Comment: You can find the google_check.xml and the sun version as well in the actual jar file in the plug in directory. net.sf.eclipsecs.checkstyle_XXXXXXXXXXXX.jar. Inside the jar file is another jar file named: checkstyle-XXXXX-all.jar. In this jar file you'll find the xml files.